# How to display an IconButton that is hidden on button click using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have in my `ViewModel` class, a `State` object with the default value of `false`.

```
var menuState = mutableStateOf(false)
```

Now I want to display the `IconButton` according to the value of `menuState`:

```
setContent {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar (
                title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "MyApp",
                        fontSize = 18.sp
                    )
                    if (viewModel.menuState.value) { //Condition
                        IconButton(
                            onClick = {
                                //Do stuff
                            }
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Outlined.MoreVert,
                                contentDescription = null,
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

This code works fine, when the app starts, since I want the `IconButton` to be hidden. Now the problem comes when I want to change the visibility from another composable on button click:

```
Button(
    onClick = {
        viewModel.menuState.value = true
    }
) {
    Text(
        text = "Sign out",
        fontSize = 18.sp
    )
}
```

Nothing happens. The `IconButton` remains hidden. How to solve this?

Comment: This code seems good to me. Try changing your `menuState` to `val` from `var`.

Comment: @ArpitShukla Thanks, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you add some more code in the question? Like how are the two composables connected and whether you are changing `viewModel.menuState.value` in some other place as well?

Comment: @ArpitShukla That's the only part where I try to change the value. The fact is that right after I use `viewModel.menuState.value = true` inside onClick and I log the new value, it's correct, the value is changed to true, but the IconButton doesn't appear. The new value is somehow not propagated. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe your composable is getting recomposed but is positioned wrong. 1) Set the initial value of `menuState` to `true` and check if it is displayed in the start or not. 2) Wrap everything inside topAppBar `title` in a `Row`

Comment: @ArpitShukla 1) If I set the initial value to true, yes, it's shown. 2) I already did that. Do you think that it would be better to have distinct AppBar for each screen?

Comment: Right now, are you changing this state from multiple screens sharing a common scaffold?

Comment: @ArpitShukla No, I think different scaffolds. May be this be the problem?

Comment: It's hard to guess anything with this much of code. Everything is correct in the code you shared. Are you sure you have the same view model instance everywhere? Because if you are changing `menuState` in one view model and observing `menuState` of a different instance, that won't work.

Comment: @ArpitShukla Yes, that's the same instance as it's added using hiltViewModel().

Comment: Can you once put a log statement inside your view model's `init` block and verify that the log is printed just once?

Comment: Are you using compose navigation, or multiple fragments/activities? view model won't be the same in different destinations

Answer (score 1):

Try out this way:

Create Composable method for TopBar and pass boolean parameter

```
@Composable
fun TopBar(isVisible: Boolean) {
    TopAppBar (
        title = {
            Text(
                text = "MyApp",
                fontSize = 18.sp
            )
            if (isVisible) { //Condition
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        //Do stuff
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Outlined.MoreVert,
                        contentDescription = null,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

After that call this method:

```
setContent {
    Scaffold(
        topBar =  TopBar(viewModel.menuState.value)       }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  but how does it make the difference?

Comment: Composable recompose whenever change it's state value. It's changed value based on it parameter value change. see https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition

Comment: Ok, thanks. Let me try that.

Comment: Please,  Give up vote if it is working.

Comment: I will upvote and accept the answer, as soon as I make it work, but this solution doesn't work. I just tried it :| Do you have any other idea?