# How to make Dialog re-measure when a child size changes dynamically?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I implemented a simple dialog with Jetpack Compose on Android.

I am trying to show a caution message when `isRehearsal` is `true`.

The variable `isRehearsal` is toggled when the user clicks buttons, and changing button works fine when the user clicks the buttons and toggles `isRehearal`.

The problem is, that the caution text does not appear when the initial value of `isRehearsal` is `false` and later the variable becomes `true`. When I change the initial value of `isRehearsal` to `true`, then the text disappears/appears fine when `isRehearsal` becomes `false` or `true`.

```kotlin
var isRehearsal by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = { dismiss() },
    DialogProperties(dismissOnBackPress = true, dismissOnClickOutside = true)
) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(12.dp)
    ) { // the box does not resize when the caution text appears dynamically.
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Set speed")
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                if (isRehearsal) {
                    Button(
                        onClick = { isRehearsal = false },
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                            backgroundColor = Colors.Red400
                        )
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Rehearsal ON")
                    }
                } else {
                    Button(
                        onClick = { isRehearsal = true },
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                            backgroundColor = Colors.Green400
                        )
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Rehearsal OFF")
                    }
                }
                Button(onClick = { onClickStart(pickerValue) }) {
                    Text(text = "Start")
                }
            }
            if (isRehearsal) { // BUG!! when the intial value of isRehearsal is false, then the text never appears even when the value becomes true.
                Text(text = "Rehearsal does not count as high score") // <- The caution text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How should I change the `Box` block to make the box's height extend properly to be able to wrap caution text when a view appears dynamically?

**Edit**
If I change the catuion message part to like below, the text appears fine even when the initial value of `isRehearsal` is `false`. Therefore, I think that the issue is with the height of the `Box` composable.

```
if (isRehearsal) {
    Text(text = "Rehearsal does not count as high score")
} else {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp))
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70108811/8614565

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the topmost `Dialog` view size is not getting updated after the first recomposition. It's a [known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221643630).

As a workaround until it's fixed, you can make a transparent topmost view take all the size available, and handle clicks same as `dismissOnClickOutside` option does:

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = { },
) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = null,
            ) {
                // same action as in onDismissRequest
            }
    ) {
        // content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use DialogProperties() with

> usePlatformDefaultWidth = false

as a workaround. Example:

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = {},
    properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)
) {
   Card(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp).wrapContentSize().animateContentSize()) {
        // content
  }
}
```